# Access to private key of SSL cert

Tags: asp.net, security, cryptography, ssl-certificate, wif

Is it okay to give Network Service access to the site's SSL certificates private key from a security point of view?

EDIT: adding some context to the question
In this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh289318.aspx), under section "Encrypt cookies using RSA" step 4, the code uses the  "serviceCertificate" to encrypt and sign the cookie. Access to the cert's private key is required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safest not to have any access beyond that which is strictly necessary. Access to secret and private keys is very important in key management. To make sure you are not introducing vulnerabilities, it is also pretty important not to use private keys outside their use case (e.g. authentication in SSL is different from signing data).

Security is about layers. The more and better secured layers you can introduce, the safer you are. Limiting access is a very high good. So if it can be avoided, don't mix your transport layer and application layer.

At our company we always create separate certificates for different uses. We try to keep the SSL handling and application handling on different servers. The application server only gets fed the authentication details.

That said, I'm employed at a company that focuses on security. You can obviously use less stringent security, but it's a good thing if you make some well thought out security policy around it. If you're not sure, hire a consultant.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean services like apache... you would have no choice. The alternative would be to enter the passwort on every startup - but even then the software has access to the key.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if somebody manages to hack your web script (via SQL injection or whatever) such that copy of private key is downloaded by evil hacker, then that hacker will be able to establish fake SSL server that impersionifies yours. However, to be really successful, hacker also needs to inject bogus DNS records such that bogus server has matching host name.

Having said that, it is difficult to not open access to private key to web server itself - otherwise you will have to type private key password every time you restart web server.